# OpenVPN connection timing out

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've been trying to get my vpn running on my ubuntu build for a few months now.For some reason, any connection I attempt always times out. I've been using [this guide](https://privatevpn.com/support/getting-started/linux/linux/network-manager-tun-recommended) and though I follow the directions exactly the error persists. When I run `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` and attempt to connect, I get the following log.

```
Jul 22 18:07:00 me nm-openvpn[8935]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]192.121.82.3:443
Jul 22 18:07:00 me nm-openvpn[8935]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 22 18:07:00 me nm-openvpn[8935]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 22 18:08:00 me NetworkManager[1728]: <warn>  [1532308080.5164] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4390,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Jul 22 18:08:00 me nm-openvpn-serv[8932]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Jul 22 18:08:00 me nm-openvpn[8935]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Jul 22 18:08:00 me NetworkManager[1728]: <warn>  [1532308080.5212] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4390,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Jul 22 18:08:00 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308080.5214] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4390,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Jul 22 18:08:00 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308080.5227] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4390,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Jul 22 18:08:34 me org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2605]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x4a00007 (Image View)
Jul 22 18:09:42 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308182.8333] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f" name="LA" pid=2605 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul 22 18:09:42 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308182.8475] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 9034
Jul 22 18:09:42 me nm-openvpn[9037]: WARNING: file '/home/me/Downloads/PrivateVPN-TUN-CBC/TCP/ta.key' is group or others accessible
Jul 22 18:09:42 me NetworkManager[1728]: Sun Jul 22 18:09:42 2018 Note: option tun-ipv6 is ignored because modern operating systems do not need special IPv6 tun handling anymore.
Jul 22 18:09:42 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308182.8580] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Jul 22 18:09:42 me nm-openvpn[9037]: OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 10 2018
Jul 22 18:09:42 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308182.8656] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Jul 22 18:09:42 me nm-openvpn[9037]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017, LZO 2.08
Jul 22 18:09:42 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308182.8657] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Jul 22 18:09:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jul 22 18:09:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]192.121.82.3:443
Jul 22 18:09:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: UDP link local: (not bound)
Jul 22 18:09:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]192.121.82.3:443
Jul 22 18:09:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 22 18:09:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 22 18:10:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Jul 22 18:10:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Jul 22 18:10:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Jul 22 18:10:43 me NetworkManager[1728]: <warn>  [1532308243.5117] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Jul 22 18:10:43 me nm-openvpn-serv[9034]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Jul 22 18:10:43 me nm-openvpn[9037]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
Jul 22 18:10:43 me NetworkManager[1728]: <warn>  [1532308243.5177] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Jul 22 18:10:43 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308243.5180] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Jul 22 18:10:43 me NetworkManager[1728]: <info>  [1532308243.5182] vpn-connection[0x5567fb5d4590,0a67e056-53c9-462f-87bf-92659c922b8f,"LA",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

If there are any more commands that I can run to get more information, please let me know. Additionally, would this problem persist if I switched my vpn provider?

Thanks in advance